# Powershell Script to run Python Script

Tags: python, powershell, scripting, powershell-3.0

I need to run a python script on windows environment using powershell as an option only as my Bamboo Env will invoke that only.

I need powershell script which will call python script and should fail if python return status as 1.
I'm not able to do so, can you please help me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [`$LASTEXITCODE` automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables).

> **$LASTEXITCODE**
>
> Contains the exit code of the last Windows-based program that was run.

A sample Powershell script (apply [`.` Dot sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators) to run a python script):

```
. py SomePythonScript.py
if ( $LASTEXITCODE -ne 0 ) { 
   Write-Warning "Exiting with code $LASTEXITCODE" 
   exit $LASTEXITCODE
}
### sample Powershell script continues here on `$LASTEXITCODE -eq 0` condition
```

Comment: Thank-You so much @JosefZ . It is working as expected.